# How can I disable widget from being visible on some pages?

Tags: plugins, widgets, plugin-recommendation

I have two widgets in my sidebar, a jQuery vertical menu and an image handler.

I need to disable the jQuery widget on my contact page (or hide it or something like this),  so that it wont be shown.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1):

There are some plugins that will allow you to do so. But if you prefer total control over the code, then [this post](http://blog.rutwick.com/show-or-hide-a-wp-widget-only-on-specific-pages) should help you.

Comment: If there is a plugin to do so, can you please suggest me one? thanx in advance.

Comment: You're welcome... Dynamic Widgets is one such plugin...

Comment: Link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/

Answer (score 0):

The [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/) plugin does this by tacking a block of settings onto the bottom of each widget's box. The options are a bit involved, so you should just look at the screenshot for a feel of whether it can take care of your particular requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not to be compatible with my wordpress version (3.3.1). Thanx anyway :)

Comment: Odd. It works for me, despite the compatibility version listed on the plugin page; those are often way out of date. Did you actually try it, or just go by that? The other one Rutwick brought up is more recent, anyway, but also takes a slightly different approach.